# Are uploaded images supposed to be included in Cognito Forms confirmation email?

Tags: cognito-forms

Are the uploaded images supposed to be included in the confirmation emails? I am not receiving the images in confirmations

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/). Currently, we do not include the images with email notifications. However, this is a feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/7VPCTjlt/131-attach-or-link-files-to-email-notifications) that we are looking to add in the future. Please feel free to provide us feedback on this feature. A lot of times, what we decide to work on next is based on your feedback.

Comment: There is now an option to include uploaded files as attachments to email notifications.